# Masking a CCLayer

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a `CCLayer` (`itemLayer`) that has a bunch of `CCMenuItemImage` (`itemButton`) objects in it placed vertically in  a column. These `itemButton` objects go way past the bounds of the screen and the `itemLayer` is sized accordingly to fit all `itemButton` objects it contains (for example, an `itemButton` object is sized 50px high and `itemLayer` has 30 of it, `itemLayer` will then have 1500px as its height).

However, this `itemLayer` object's **visible area** only needs to be 500px high. Is it possible to somehow mask this `itemLayer` object so that the user only sees 500px of it but still be able to scroll through the whole list of `itemButton` objects?

Comment: Wouldn't you size your layer and use a CCScrollView?

Comment: Have you tried `ClippingRectangleNode` or `CCClippingNode` ?